# How to Validate date field in Apigee Edge

Tags: apigee

I want to validate a date field in Apigee and raise fault if the date is not of specific format.

Example: I want to pass a date and check if the date is of the given format "mm/dd/yyyy". If the date is not if this format I need to raise a fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to use a script callout. I'd recommend javascript for simplicity's sake. Assuming you already extracted the date using an ExtractVariables policy, a simple validation might look like:

```
var date = context.getVariable("date").split("/");
date.map(function(d) { return parseInt(d) });
if (date.length < 3) {
    // raise fault
} else {
    if (date[0] >= 1 && date[0] <= 12 &&
        date[1] >= 1 && date[1] <= 31 &&
        date[0] >= 1970 && date[0] <= 3000) {
        // probably a good date
    } else {
        //raise fault
    }
}
```

Now, that written, it doesn't actually validate months to number of days or leap years or anything fancy. If you need it pinpoint accurate, I'd recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) as an [included resource](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/reference/javascript-policy) on the javascript callout.

Keep in mind too that this is a quickly written example, and isn't robust enough to handle an assortment of bad inputs. I'd recommend using a try/catch block at the very least.

Comment: This helps. Will try to implement this way.

Comment: How to call raise fault in the else statement in this java script? Any help.

Comment: @user you can use the JavaScript context to set the HTTP code to say 400, then have a conditional raise fault step that only executed if code != 200.